# What does git pull <link-to-remote> do?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-pull

A newer git user at my job mistakenly ran the command

`git pull https://github.com/our-repo.git`

What they meant to do was:

`git clone https://github.com/our-repo.git`

or at least

`git remote add origin https://github.com/our-repo.git`

`git pull origin master`

Yet `git pull https://github.com/our-repo.git` seemed to have pulled in some code but obviously it did not create an `origin` or any branches.

What exactly would `git pull <url-to-remote>` actually do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Since your Git did not know anything about a named remote, Git simply asked the other Git what it recommended—specifically, what its HEAD was.  Your Git then used this for both the fetch and merge steps.

In other words, this was the equivalent of:

```
git pull <url> HEAD
```

which leaves some oddities to be explained.

#### Long

As the other two answerers so far have said, `git pull` simply runs `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, typically `git merge`.  The tricky part lies in *how* `git pull` runs the two commands, and what they then do.

If you enter, on the command line:

```
git pull abc bra
```

then the `abc` part is treated as a *remote or repository*, and the `bra` part is treated as a *refspec*.  Git then runs:

```
git fetch abc bra
```

If you omit the `bra` part—the refspec—from the `git pull` command, Git simply runs:

```
git fetch abc
```

i.e., it omits the refspecs from the `fetch` step too.  (Note that *every* non-option argument after the remote-or-repository is a refspec, but it's unwise in general to put more than one on the command line.)

If you omit *both* names, `git pull` will run `git fetch` with *neither* remote *nor* refspec arguments.  So now we need to look at what `git fetch` does with its remote-or-repository, and refspec, arguments.

#### What `git fetch` fetches

You—or your `git pull`—will run a `git fetch` with:

- no named remote-or-repository and no refspecs; or
- one named remote-or-repository and no refspecs; or
- one named remote-or-repository and one or more refspecs.

In the first case, `git fetch` figures out a remote to use based on your current branch (it runs the equivalent of `git config --get branch.branch.remote`), or if that fails, assumes `origin`.  In the second or third cases, you can give it a remote name like `origin`, or you can give it a URL like `https://github.com/our-repo.git`.  Since the first case translates into the second case, we have only the two cases here to worry about.

If you use a *named remote* like `origin`, your Git look up `remote.origin.url` to get the URL, and also `remote.origin.fetch`.  Typically `remote.origin.fetch` is set to exactly this:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Thus, when you run `git fetch origin`, your Git fetches *all* the branches the other Git offers, turning them into remote-tracking names.  When you run `git fetch origin bra`, your Git fetches only whatever is required to fetch `bra` (I'm assuming here that `bra` is a branch name).  If your Git is at least 1.8.4, it still does the same renaming, so that this updates `refs/remotes/origin/bra`, too.

When you give your Git a raw URL, though, it probably won't find a `remote.https://github.com/our-repo.git.fetch` configuration (it might not even try to look that up, but if it does, it won't find anything).  It still knows what *URL* to contact, so it contacts a Git there; but it does not have a specific `fetch =` directive.  If you give `git fetch` a branch name, your Git will ask their Git for that branch.  But you didn't do that either—so your Git just asks their Git: *Hey, other Git, what do you have set up as `HEAD`?*

So you say nothing, and their Git gives you a hash ID to go with *their* `HEAD`, and your Git writes this to `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  Or, you say "give me your branch `bra`", and their Git gives you a hash ID to go with their `refs/heads/bra`, and your Git writes this to `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  In either case, *nothing happens to any remote-tracking names.*  There's no named remote, so there's no way to update the right remote-tracking name.

Still, your Git always writes everything it fetches to `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, *whether or not if it updates a name like `origin/master` or `origin/develop`*.  This is partly an ancient backwards-compatibility thing—except that `git pull` still uses it, as we'll see in a moment.

#### What the `git merge` run by `git pull` merges

This step is simpler than the fetch step in several ways, but still pretty tricky.  When `git pull` runs `git merge`, it pre-sets some options and arguments:

- `-m`: `git pull` always supplies an initial merge message.  It's not a very *good* merge message, but it does supply one.  (By default it makes you edit this merge message if there is an actual merge involved.)
- Other options from `git pull`: if you use `--ff` or `--no-ff` or `--ff-only`, or `-s strategy`, or various other options listed in [the documentation](https://github.com/our-repo.git), `git pull` passes those through to `git merge`.
- One or more raw commit IDs.

After `git fetch` leaves its tracks behind in `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, the `git pull` code reads through the file.  In that file, Git has recorded every branch-tip commit that it fetched.  In some cases, there's only one such commit.  (That's true for this case of fetching `HEAD`, for instance.)  In others—none of which apply to this particular case, but we should remember them for completeness—it lists more; but it marks most of them `not-for-merge`.  The ones it *doesn't* mark are the ones that correspond to the refspec names you gave on the command line, such as `bra`, or—if you didn't name any on the command line—the one from `branch.branch.merge`, if you fetched from a named remote.

In any case, `git pull` extracts whatever `git fetch` *didn't* mark as "not for merge".  Ideally that's just one commit hash, because otherwise your `git pull` is invoking `git merge` so as to make an *octopus merge*.  This is rarely what you want—if you don't know what it is, you definitely don't want it!—so you'll be happier if there is just one hash ID involved (as is the case here).

At this point, `git merge` does what it always does, based on the options and arguments.  Git computes the merge base from the current commit—your own repository's `HEAD`—and the argument commit(s).  If the merge base is the same as the other (single) commit, there is nothing to merge: Git says so and does nothing.  If the merge base is `HEAD`, a fast-forward not-really-a-merge is possible; Git does this if you haven't forbidden it.  Otherwise, a real merge is required, and Git does this if you haven't forbidden it.

Upon completing, failing to complete (stopping in the middle to get help from you-the-user), or not even trying the merge, `git merge` exits, and now `git pull` is done.

#### Conclusion

By running `git pull` with a URL, you have asked the other Git to send you its `HEAD` (probably `master`) commit, plus any other commits required, and then merged that commit into your current branch, whatever your current branch is.  By using a URL instead of `origin`, you have disabled your own Git's update of `origin/master` or any other `origin/*` names.  So if a merge or fast-forward was needed to bring in their `HEAD`, and was not prohibited, it's either done now or in that half-done state of a failed merge.

Answer (score 0):

The pull command is used to make a **git fetch** followed by a **git merge** in a single command.

The fetch command imports the information from the remote repository. The import is done through special branches to give us the possibility to compare.

git merge . Merges the  branch with the current branch

Comment: thank you for your response. I understand the usage of git pull (fetch + merge) but what is the difference (if any) between pulling from an origin <branch> vs. a URL to a remote? ex. git pull origin master vs. git pull https://github.com/somerepo.git

Comment: the name origin is just an alias to replace url with a name,  when you run remote origin some@github.com/User/repo, you create a new remote, which name is origin.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question.

Let's say If you already have a cloned copy of a repository and there are many developers working on the repository and recently there is a pull request merged in the remote repository and now the remote is 1 commit ahead of the forked/local repository.
Now to keep local/forked repo even with the remote repository we have to `git pull`  the remote and then `git push` to keep the local and forked even with the remote repository.

For more detailed info, Please go through this:https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Answer (score 0):

It is short for 
    `git pull <URL> HEAD`

Where HEAD is can be found by 
    `cat .git/FETCH_HEAD`

Example:

```
  cat .git/FETCH_HEAD
      b521bea1b4b336864462e
```

Comment: `HEAD` and `FETCH_HEAD` are actually different things. Check `.git/HEAD` for `HEAD`